# Help with a guess my number program in python

Tags: python, logic

I'm trying to write a python program in which the program guesses the users number. I fel like an idiot, the part i am getting caught up on is the math, i feel like its one of those things where I've been working on it for a few hours and someone else would be able to bring a fresh perspective and solve it easily. I figured to start off I would take the user component out of it almost completely. Here is what I have so far, its getting stuck on the logic part and eventually just keeps saying its either too low or too high, for infinity:

```
MIN=0
MAX=100
firstguess = MAX - MIN
firstguess = firstguess/2

while 1==1:
number = int(raw_input("Enter your number 0-100:"))
print firstguess
oldguess = firstguess
if firstguess > number:
    print "First guess is too high."
    raw_input()
    guess = int(25)
    print guess
    while guess != number:
        if guess > number:
            print "My guess was too high."
            raw_input()
            nextguess = oldguess - guess
            nextguess = nextguess/2
            nextguess = guess - nextguess
            oldguess = guess
            guess = nextguess
        elif guess == number:
            print "I win!"
            exit
        elif guess < number:
            print "My guess was too low."
            raw_input()
            nextguess = oldguess - guess
            nextguess = nextguess/2
            nextguess = nextguess + guess
            oldguess = guess
            guess = nextguess
elif firstguess == number:
    print "I win!"
elif firstguess < number:
    print "My first guess was too low."
    raw_input()
    guess = 75
    print guess
    print guess
    while guess != number:
        if guess > number:
            print "My guess was too high."
            raw_input()
            nextguess = oldguess - guess
            nextguess = nextguess/2
            nextguess = guess - nextguess
            oldguess = guess
            guess = nextguess
        elif guess == number:
            print "I win!"
            exit
        elif guess < number:
            print "My guess was too low."
            raw_input()
            nextguess = oldguess - guess
            nextguess = nextguess/2
            nextguess = nextguess + guess
            oldguess = guess
            guess = nextguess
```

Comment: *Cough* Homework *Cough*

Comment: Not an answer but: The first and most important principle when doing software design, is to recognize patterns. Your code have 4 very similar parts, you should probably -refactor- the code and extract the similar parts into one function. Actually, successful software development is mostly about discovering patterns, and generalize stuff, in the code or in the real world...

Comment: Hey guys, I would like you to know that it actually wasn't homework, my school doesn not offer programming classes, so I am teaching myself.

Comment: This is from a course at https://class.coursera.org, where you have to abide by an honour code.  Uve breached that code.

https://class.coursera.org/interactivepython-2012-001/wiki/view?page=honorcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be doing your homework, but you seemed to make an honest attempt at the problem:

```
bounds = [0, 100]
minimum, maximum = bounds

number = int(raw_input('Pick a number [{0}-{1}]: '.format(minimum, maximum)))

while guess != number:
  guess = int((maximum + minimum) / 2)
  raw_input('Guessing {0}'.format(guess))

  if guess > number:
    maximum = guess
  elif guess < number:
    maximum = bounds[1]
    minimum = guess

print 'I win!'
```

The logic is simple:

1. Choose lower and upper bounds for the guesses.
2. Have the user pick a number, stored as `number`.
3. While the guess is not equal to the number:

   1. Choose the midpoint between the minimum and maximum range bounds.
   2. If the guess is bigger than the number, then the number must be smaller than the guess, so we set the maximum guess bound to be the current guess.
   3. If the guess is smaller than the number, then we set the maximum to be the highest number possible and the minimum to be the guess.
4. Once the guess is the number, the loop breaks and we win.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so 1) I don't know python and 2) I have no idea what your code does and can't be bothered figuring it out. Why? Because I think you're overcomplicating it.

I believe you can solve this with a simple binary search. In pseudocode:

```
low = 0                        // lowest possible value of user's number
high = 100                     // highest possible value of user's number

while low < high
    guess = (low + high) / 2   // guess the average of low and hight
    if guess is too low        // if guess is too low
        then low = guess + 1   // then the lowest possible value is guess + 1
    if guess it too high       // if guess is too high
        then hight = guess - 1 // then the highest possible value is guess - 1
    if guess equals the value
        we've found the answer

at this point (low + high) / 2 should be the answer
```

The algorithm halves the search space and checks on which side the user's number is. Example run in the range `1-10` where the user's number is `3`. `L` represents low, `H` represents high and `G` represents guess:

```
L         G         H  | guess is too high so we set high to guess-1
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 |
                       |
L   G   H              | guess is too low so we set low to guess+1
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 |
                       |
      L H              | guess is in the same position as low and is correct so
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | we've found the number
```